# Angularjs How to mask unmask whole body when click on any link

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on **Angularjs** and didn't find any way to **mask-unmask** my html body or div.
I tried **ng-show** but that will not work in my case.
Could any one please let me know how I can disable all option using anuglarjs either using masking unmasking or some loading screen.

**Edited:**
I want my screen disabled till my http request not returned from the server. In Jquery this can be achieved using masking and unmasking

Comment: what you mean by mask-unmask??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VWAhC/ something like this???

Comment: @Arpit I updated my question. please let me know if you want any more information from me.

Comment: @BijayRai Thanks for the sample but I didn't find the disable screen in the example you provided.

Comment: probably you just add a layer on top of parent div using `position:fixed` and `overflow:hidden` and hide when you get successful call

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManagerStandard

Specifically this file:

CustomerManager\app\wc.directives\directives\wcOverlay.js

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help uh... 
you should *show* some overlay before http request and after getting response from server then just hide that overlay...

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $("#overlay").show();
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php")
        .success(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response;
        $("#overlay").hide();
    });
});

#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

Here is working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BijayRai/Lc8eL20d/1/)
hope this will help uh... :)